# Apache Beam - How to sum over PCollection<KV<String, Int>> from all windows by key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Given a `PCollection<KV<String, Int>>` with fixed-time windowing, how can I sum all the `Int` by the `String` key from all **windows**?

e.g.

```
PCollection<KV<String, Int>> pc = ...;  

pc.apply("FixedWindows", Window.<~>into(FixedWindows.of(WindowDuration)) // apply fixed windowing
```

How can I sum over **all windows** by each key in this setting?

Should I use `Combine.GloballyAsSingletonView<InputT,OutputT>` with a custom CombineFn? if so, how should I implement it?

Comment: What do you mean with sum over all windows?

Comment: I have hourly-windows, but I need to have a sum of all hours. So I wish to sum over all windows I have

Comment: What do you mean with all windows? All the windows for a day, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Combine is always scoped to the windowing you have applied.  To sum across all elements, you'll need to Window back into GlobalWindows first

Comment: How about the triggers? If I have early/on-time/late triggers on the original window, and I window back into 1 GlobalWindow, when will the results be calculated and emitted?

Comment: You'll need to explicitly specify the triggering that you want for the global aggregation

Answer (score 0):

One of the options, in case you don't have too many different keys and the sum result is less than `Long.MAX_VALUE`, you can use [Beam Metrics](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#types-of-metrics), like `Counter`, for that.